# Auth0 integration

Tags: authentication, dashboard

I’m working on a project where I’m creating a platform in which to use it, customers need to log in and each customers dashboard will be specific to them- think like a bank account log in.

I’m want to use Auth0 for this. I would like it to have the customer type in an email, send the customer a one time passcode for authentications and then have the customer dashboard open. Is this possible?

I’ve tried it on ALT0 but have failed so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this. Are you familiar with TOTP and [mult-factor authentication](https://fusionauth.io/docs/lifecycle/authenticate-users/multi-factor-authentication)? Some features may cost and some may be free.  You might want to check this out.